# Como llevar datos de javascript a un modelo en codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Estoy realizando un aplicacion usando codeigniter y quisiera saber como podria llevar la informacion que recuperé de una etiqueta select en un archivo javascript para llevarlo a una variable en mi modelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas realizar una petición [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) contra una ruta establecida por ti en el servidor PHP CodeIgniter enviándole los datos que necesitas y recibiendo una respuesta (normalmente en formato JSON) de si ha ido bien o no tu petición al servidor con los datos de respuesta.

> Aquí tienes un ejemplo de una petición AJAX simple:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      // Success!
      var resp = this.responseText;
    } else {
      // Error :(
    }
  }
};

request.send();
request = null;
```

[Fuente](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)